# ¿Ejecutar un stored procedure con Entity FrameWork?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Estoy tratando de ejecutar un SP que no me devuelve un resultado (no genera algun tipo complejo ni entidad), pero este no aparece como funcion en el context del EF, me falta algun paso o de que manera puedo ejecutarlo, este SP tiene parametros de entrada.

```
var context = (BD_BROKER_LIQUIDACION_ENTITIES)UnidadDeTrabajo;
context.SP????<-- aqui no aparece mi funcion
```

Comment: Si `context` es un elemento que hereda de `DbContext` entonces puedes hacer: [`context.Database.SqlQuery<TIPO_QUE_RETORNA_QUERY>("Query", parámetros);`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696545(v=vs.113).aspx)

Comment: en este caso no retorna ningun tipo el query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esta fue la opcion que me resulto para enviar parametros y ejecutar el el SP, al final no es necesario mapear el sp en el modelo.

```
ObjectParameter oPVC_MES_ARCHIVOParameter = new ObjectParameter("OPVC_MES_ARCHIVO", Periodo);
                ObjectParameter iD_USUARIOParameter = new ObjectParameter("ID_USUARIO", objCredenciales.USUARIO);
                context.ExecuteFunction("SPIN_SAVE_VALIDADOR", oPVC_MES_ARCHIVOParameter, iD_USUARIOParameter);
```